# Sass convert string to color

Tags: colors, sass

I am using `mdl`, which has color variables setup like `$color-primary: '255, 0, 0' !default;`

This is making it hard for me to take that color and lighten it.

I have tried using `unquote()`, but it is giving me an error:

> Argument `$color` of `lighten($color, $amount)` must be a color

```
$color-primary: '255, 0, 0' !default;
$light-accent: lighten(unquote('rgb(#{$color-primary})'), 13.5%) !default;
```

Is there someway I can convert that to a color?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem. You've found in the [MDL source](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/88872e672e41c56af0a78a35b34373b8c4a8c49d/src/_color-definitions.scss#L146) that `$color-primary` is actually just a string that includes quotes: `"63,81,181"`.

Here's the tricky part: MDL is using these strings everywhere. They aren't actually ever evaluating those colours in a way that SASS understands them. So this:

```
unquote('rgb(#{$color-primary})')
```

doesn't return the SASS [`rgb()` instance method](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#rgb-instance_method), it just returns a plain ol' string.

That's a long way of saying that I don't think you can do what you're looking to do. You can use the other colours in the [MDL `$palette-indigo`](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/88872e672e41c56af0a78a35b34373b8c4a8c49d/src/_color-definitions.scss#L162), though, in the format `$palette-indigo-xxx` (photo from [material.io](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette)).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you couldn't use string as input for colors method
[codepen](https://codepen.io/roshanakjamali/pen/ExxeobY?editors=0100)

```
$color-primary: '255, 0, 0' !default;
$light-accent: lighten(convertStringToColor($color-primary), 40.5%) !default;

body{
  background: convertStringToColor($color-primary);
}

h1{
  color: $light-accent;
}
```